# Make modal undismissable javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a modal on my website, but I want to make that modal not dismissable when the progress is running, is there any way to do it? I'm using bootstrap and JQuery in case there may be things that affected by that

Comment: If ur using Bootstrap modal, you can disabled all closing behaviors with attributes "backdrop static" and "keyboard". Some examples here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#options

Comment: @ThanhDao yeah actually that answer my question